# How can i make my tetris block rotate withouth hardcoding every possible rotation for every block

Tags: javascript, tetris

i have an array that will contain four tetromino object

```
const canvasWidth = 600;
const tetrominoSpawnArray = [];
```

i have a  tetromino class:

```
export default class Tetromino {
// the moviment scale of 30
constructor(x,y,color) {
    this.width = 30;
    this.height = 30;
    this.color = color;
    this.totalWidth;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xVelocity = 30;
    this.yVelocity = 30;
}
```

in this class there is a method that generate 4 tetromino and push it in an array with the x and y based on the type of tetromino that was randomply picked

```
const randomIndex = Math.ceil(Math.random() * tetrominoTypeAndColor.nonUsedBlock.length - 1);        
// type of block randomly picked 
    switch (tetrominoTypeAndColor.nonUsedBlock[randomIndex]) {
        case 'I':                 
             // x y color are the required parameter
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(240,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 4;
            break;
        case 'J':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 3;
            break;
        case 'L':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 3;
            break;
        case 'O':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 2;
            break;
        case 'S':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 3;
            break;
        case 'T':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 3;
            break;
        case 'Z':
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(330,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(300,30,tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            tetrominoSpawnArray.push(new Tetromino(270,0, tetrominoTypeAndColor.color[randomIndex]));
            this.totalWidth = this.width * 3;
            break;
    }
```

this work fine and generate 4 tetromino in the correct position, the problem come when i attempt to rotate them.

is there an algorithm that take the x and the y of my 4 tetromino object in the array and modify it by rotating the tetromino? or should i hard code every possible rotation for every type of block?

Comment: In the code you've shown, the `Tetromino` class doesn't have any properties that would support a meaningful rotation operation. (Regarding shape, it only has a width and height, and they're the same static value).

Comment: What proprieties my class doesn't have? these proprieties are sufficient to draw and move the tetromino, (i have an event listener that move the four tetromino object based on the keyboard input)

Comment: also to make life easier, define your blocks and "playing field" in block coordinates, rather than pixels. and let your draw code determine how to place "four blocks (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,1) at height offset 5" as 150,150 etc. Makes writing rotation code a lot simpler, too.

Comment: mhh, seems a goo idea, but i don't understand how can i implement that.